# Is there any verb omitted in this sentence? (LLPSI)

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In *Lingua Latin per se Illustrata*: Chapter 32, Line 158:

> Sed frūstrā hoc optō, nam iam illī pīrātae eam spem mihi ēripient, idque eōdem diē quō ab amīcā meā dēsertus sum.

***dēsertus sum*** seems to be the verb of the ***quō***-clause (*the same day in which I am deserted by my girlfriend*), and where is the verb for the outer clause (which seems to have ***id*** as the subject)? Is it omitted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the verb is omitted. You can imagine the sentence going *idque **fit*** (or *fiet*) *eodem die quo ...* (and this happens/will happen on the same day as ...).

The same omission is often seen in English too: "and this on the day when ..."

Comment: Note: I had originally overlooked the fact that the narration is in the present/future. I edited the answer accordingly.